# how to get the height of a xaml row

Tags: wpf, xaml

My boss is asking me for the percentage of the height for rows in different xaml pages we use.  The row heights are defined as either 'Auto' or '*'.  This was a quick solution I thought of to try to get the the heights, and after that I could do the math to get the percentage that each row takes.  Unfortunately, it writes '0' for each console.writeline operation.  Is there another way to do this?

```
public TestPageConstructor()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight);
   Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight);
   Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight);
   Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[3].ActualHeight);
   Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[4].ActualHeight);
}
```

Comment: For the `Auto` just grab the actualheight of the largest element within a row since that's what's dictating it for that instance. As for the `*` well unless you have fixed sizes on your app could be dynamic based on whatever the parent is and would be kind of tough to provide as some sort of a predictable fixed number....

Comment: I'm trying to grab the actual height, but it's returning as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run your code after that your Grid Loaded, not in constructor.

Sample Xaml Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="mygrid" Loaded="Mygrid_OnLoaded">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

C# Code :

```
public TestPageConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Mygrid_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight);
    Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight);
    Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight);
    Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[3].ActualHeight);
    Console.WriteLine(mygrid.RowDefinitions[4].ActualHeight);  
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: :)).My pleasure, I'm glad that worked for you, constructor is not a good place to accessing our UI controls.